# Add existing element to Object

Tags: javascript

I have next object:

```
    var myArray = new Object();

    myArray["firstname"] = "Gareth";
    myArray["lastname"] = "Simpson";
```

Also I have function that returns elements (it's value depends from different conditions):

```
function getNewElement(condition1, ..., conditionN) {

        ...
        return { "my btn": function() { alert(kkk); } }
}
```

How I can add to `myArray` value that returns me `getNewElement` function?

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to do but it seems to me like your approach (read: code structure) on this is a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray["fn"] = getNewElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
myArray["newElement"] = getNewElement();
```

or

```
myArray["my btn"] = getNewElement()["my btn"];
```

?

Comment: Actually I found way:
 
        for (property in getButtonToExit())
        myArray[property] = getButtonToExit()[property];

Comment: @DanTheMan: Okay, if you got it resolved, great. I can still see some place for improvement in your comment's code, but that's another issue. Feel free to accept an answer which came as close as possible to your question. Or, post the solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to create new Objects

```
    var myObj = {
            firstName : "Gareth"
            lastName  : "Simpson"
            };

function getNewElement(condition1, ..., conditionN) {
  return { "my btn": function() { alert(kkk); } } 
} 

myObj.getNewElement;

//to call the function
myObj.getNewElement();
```